# WSDL2Java error on command prompt

Tags: axis, wsdl2java

I'm having an error when im using WSDL2Java tool in command prompt. im getting

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/wsdl/WSDL2Java

Error.

can anyone help me with this? I really need the solution for this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solved this problem. i set the classpath of all the jars individually in the command prompt.

set CLASSPATH=C:\axis\lib\axis.jar;C:\axis\lib\axis-ant.jar;C:\axis\lib\commons-discovery-0.2.jar;C:\axis\lib\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;C:\axis\lib\jaxrpc.jar;C:\axis\lib\log4j-1.2.8.jar;C:\axis\lib\saaj.jar;C:\axis\lib\wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar;C:\axis\lib\activation.jar;C:\axis\lib\mailapi.jar

run this on the command prompt and run

> c:\axis>java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java [WSDL FILE] OR [WSDL URL]

the classes that is generated by WSDL2Java tool will be found on:

c:\axis\org or the directory you run the script above.

you can use this for your reference.

http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL

I hope this would help you. :)

Comment: Great, you can accept your own answer with the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows.